# How to embed plplot or matplotlib into Qt?

Tags: qt, plot

I can't find anything about how to embed plotting into Qt by using C++. Which component in Qt should be used for plotting?

I want to grasp the thing generated by these lib and display it using Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working example [at this blogpost](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/03/25#rinside_and_qt) combining embedded R with Qt. I used both SVG and PNG graphs, though the current version only uses SVG.

The repository is [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/?root=rinside), if you rewind a commit or two you get the version that flips between SVG and PNG (depending on whether a particular can be loaded).

You should be able to use the logic to show plots from either plplot or matplotlib.

Comment: I think it's overkilled. I just want to grasp the thing generated by this lib and display it on qt.

Comment: That is precisely what my app shows you: instantiate a widget, point it to a file, get display of the file.

Comment: I see that embed whole R language.
can't I just display it immediately?

Comment: can I just display it without any file outputed?

Comment: You do not need R, that is simply my example of generating a file.  Given a file, from where ever it comes, you can have Qt display it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still lookimg for a method which won't generate a file. Is that impossible?

Comment: I fear you may have your causality wrong: *Given* a file, a Qt widget can display it. Absent a file, you need to draw on a canvas.

Comment: I just guess there's a method which makes plotting library insert a graph data into memory, then qt can access the graph data from memory. But i can't find any method to do so.
can't I grasped it from memory immediately?

Comment: in real time, I have to avoid disk IO

Comment: That is a conjecture.  Anyway, for real-time plotting widgets, look at at Qwt.sf.net, it has a real-time plotting example (using generated data, and does not use file input).  They eye only captures updates every few milliseconds, so even if you update 20 or 30 times a second, you're close enough. And qt does it without flicker.

Comment: Cool. Glad to have been of help. Qt is a pretty powerful library. And Qwt provides some extra widgets that can come in handy.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Note however that QwtPlot is **2D** only. The `QwtPlot3D` (not a part of QwtPlot but still offering similar functionality in 3D) hasn't been updated in like 9 years so I'd say it's a no go.